# How to show hidden element that is dynamically generated with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The image element below is located in an AJAX script. This image is hidden, and is generated ONLY after ajax is triggered, so when I use JQuery to show it, it does not work, because the element does not exist yet.

There is a boolean variable called `isTouchScreen`. I am trying to show this element, IF the value for `isTouchScreen` is `true`.

I am new to Javascript and I am having a really hard time showing the hidden element due to it being dynamically generated. Could someone can help me solve this? Many thanks in advance.

What I tried:

```
if(isTouchScreen===true){
   $('.add-item').show();
}
```

The image element that is dynamically generated with AJAX:

```
<img class="add-item" style="display:none" src="add-item.png">
```

Comment: Why don't you put the code that shows the image in the ajax callback as well, after the image has been added to the DOM?

Comment: @elclanrs! like i said I am new to AJAX / Javascript thank you! this worked!

Comment: @elclanrs you should post your response as the answer, good one.

Comment: @buruzaemon: Check my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the condition inside the AJAX callback:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function() { // This runs if the request was succesful
    var $img = $('<img class="add-item" src="add-item.png">');
    $('yourContainer').append( $img.hide() ); // append and hide by default
    if ( isTouchScreen ) { // true is truthy, no need to compare
      $('.add-item').hide();
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues in the past which I resolved by introducing a short delay before attempting to invoke a method on an element which is being dynamically introduced into the DOM.

Perhaps something like this will help:

```
if (isTouchScreen===true) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.add-item').show();
    }, 500);
}
```

where the `500` value is measured in milliseconds.

Please see [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did not work for me. This just delays the method and does not help synchronize with ajax.